# How do I write a BASH script to download and unzip file on a Mac?

Tags: bash, macos, unzip

I need to create a bash script that will work on a mac.  It needs to download a ZIP file of a site and unzip it to a specific location.

1. Download the ZIP file (`curl -O`)
2. Unzip the files to a specific location (`unzip filename.zip path/to/save`)
3. Delete the .zip file

I need to make it so people can double-click the text file on their desktop and it will automatically run in terminal.

How do I make it so that the user can double click the icon on the desktop and it will run?  What extension does the file need?

Comment: The file needs a `.cmd` extension.

Comment: `curl -L http://example.org/file.zip | bsdtar -xvf - -C /path/to/save`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

OSX uses the same GNU sh/bash as Linux

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir /tmp/some_tmp_dir                         && \
cd /tmp/some_tmp_dir                            && \
curl -sS http://foo.bar/filename.zip > file.zip && \
unzip file.zip                                  && \
rm file.zip
```

the first line `#!/bin/sh` is so called "shebang" line and is mandatory

Comment: By default `wget` isn't installed in Mac OS. `curl` is.

Comment: Is it possible to pipe curl result directly to unzip without creating file.zip?

Comment: if you prefer to see the progress dont use the silence `-sS` flag

Comment: add `set -e` at the beginning of the file and `--fail` to the curl command if you want the script to exit if the fie couldn't be downloaded.

Comment: For Bash it is sufficient to terminate the line with `&&`. The backslashes are not required.

Answer (score 16):

BSD Tar can open a zip file and decompress through a stream.The -L or --location flag is to follow redirects. So the following will work:

```
curl --show-error --location http://example.org/file.zip | tar -xf - -C path/to/save
```

Comment: The file has to be a tar file otherwise `tar: This does not look like a tar archive`

Comment: it works for `tar` on Mac, but gives error on Linux

Comment: I just realised that duplicated this answer. It works on mac and linux for me. You might be having a redirect and not following it the `-L` param.

try `curl -SL https://www.sample-videos.com/zip/10mb.zip  | tar -xz - -C .`

Comment: can you read? this is about ZIP files, not TAR files

Comment: @iirekm and can you read that "BSD Tar" (which uses libarchive) can open a zip file. ;)

Comment: Running from my linuxmint, got error > tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header

Answer (score 8):

If you do not want change directory context, use the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

unzip-from-link() {
 local download_link=$1; shift || return 1
 local temporary_dir

 temporary_dir=$(mktemp -d) \
 && curl -LO "${download_link:-}" \
 && unzip -d "$temporary_dir" \*.zip \
 && rm -rf \*.zip \
 && mv "$temporary_dir"/* ${1:-"$HOME/Downloads"} \
 && rm -rf $temporary_dir
}
```

Usage:

```
# Either launch a new terminal and copy `git-remote-url` into the current shell process, 
# or create a shell script and add it to the PATH to enable command invocation with bash.

# Place zip contents into '~/Downloads' folder (default)
unzip-from-link "http://example.com/file.zip"

# Specify target directory
unzip-from-link "http://example.com/file.zip" "/your/path/here"
```

Output:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 17.8M  100 17.8M    0     0  22.6M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 22.6M
Archive:  file.zip
  inflating: /tmp/tmp.R5KFNvgYxr/binary
```