# Pipe curl output into unzip

Tags: curl, gitlab, pipe, unzip

I'm building a CI/CD script in GitLab and want to unzip a curl output in the current dir by piping the curl output into unzip.

All the answers I could find suggests wget, tar or other tools.

Here is what I have:

```
curl -L "$URL" | unzip - -d ./output
```

Result is "Can not find output.zip so obviously unzip doesen't understand the dash placeholder when piping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use `unzip` (which might not support stdin, unless it is an option ordering issue, as in `unzip -d ./ouput -`), then it could be easier to break it down into two steps, as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8557222/6309)

```bash
curl -L "$URL" > output.zip
unzip output.zip -d ./output
```

That, or using a [dedicated script](https://serverfault.com/a/1030849/783).

---

Check if you have the `funzip` command, which should be part of the `unzip` package. `funzip` is a filter for extracting from a ZIP archive in a pipe.

Here's how you can use it:

```bash
curl -L "$URL" | funzip > output
```

Note that `funzip` will only extract the first file in the zip archive. If your zip file contains more than one file, you will need to save the file first, or use a different method.

If you're required to use `unzip`, and your environment doesn't support other unzipping tools, you may need to write to a temporary file as an intermediate step:

```bash
curl -L "$URL" -o temp.zip && unzip temp.zip -d ./output && rm temp.zip
```

This downloads the file, unzips it, and then deletes the temporary zip file. This is not as efficient as piping directly from `curl` to `unzip`, but it's a common way to work around the lack of support for piping in `unzip`.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually what I ended up doing - and then deleting the temporary .zip-file after. But I'd really like to improve the script and avoid that.
I'm bound to use unzip as that's what our shared runners support.

Comment: @esbenr OK. I have edited the answer with additional suggestions.